# How to integrate Facebook chat in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am Creating a chat application using XMPP Framework in iPhone. I want to know the process for sending and receiving messages. Can anyone give solution for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the XMPP framework documentation if you need to know more about it. Any specific problems or issues you have with it, ask questions!